# In a DataTemplate, how to bind Visibility property to collection element count?

Tags: .net, silverlight

I have a customized ItemsControl which (2 way) binds to an ObservableCollection. Each row has 1 TextBox and 2 buttons, - button will delete current row and + button will insert a new row, like this:
[image]
[image]

my data entity definition:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

    public class DeviceInfo
    {
        public DeviceInfo(string remarks)
        {
            this.Remarks = remarks;
        }
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainPageViewModel
    {
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DeviceInfo> devices = new ObservableCollection<DeviceInfo>();
        public ObservableCollection<DeviceInfo> Devices
        {
            get
            {
                return this.devices;
            }
            set
            {
                this.devices = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
<sdk:HeaderedItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Devices, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5, 5, 5, 5">
    <sdk:HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:HeaderedItemsControl">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0, 0, 5, 10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Remarks"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Width="Auto" Height="Auto" Background="White">
                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </sdk:HeaderedItemsControl.Template>
    <sdk:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </sdk:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <sdk:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Remarks}" Margin ="0, 0, 10, 10"></TextBox>
                <Button x:Name="Delete" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0, 0, 5, 10" Click="Delete_Click" Visibility="{Binding Path=Devices, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource collectionElementCountToVisibilityConverter}}">-</Button>
                <Button x:Name="Add" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0, 0, 5, 10" Click="Add_Click">+</Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </sdk:HeaderedItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</sdk:HeaderedItemsControl>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. When user clicks - or +, I want to know which DeviceInfo element is selected, so I can remove that element, or insert a new element behind it, how can I get the element in button click event handler?
2. You may notice that the - button is invisible when there are only 1 element in collection. I tried to bind the Visibility property of - button to the ItemsSource collection and returned Visibility.Collapse when the collecion's count was 1, but the binding didn't work, converter never got called, what should I do to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I solved the second question. Binding doesn't work because Button its DataContext is the element of collection, in my case that is DeviceInfo object. It tried to find a property named "Devices" in "DeviceInfo" of course that fails. I specify the datacontext and it works:

<Button x:Name="Delete" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0, 0, 5, 10" Click="Delete_Click" 
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.Devices.Count, Converter={StaticResource countToVisibilityConverter}, ElementName=DevicesList}">-</Button>

Comment: Or this also works:

<Button x:Name="Delete" 
Grid.Column="2" 
Margin="0, 0, 5, 10" 
Click="Delete_Click" 
Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.Devices.Count, 
Converter={StaticResource countToVisibilityConverter}, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=sdk:HeaderedItemsControl}}">-</Button>

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st question (since you already solved the 2nd), you can get selected `DeviceInfo` from button `DataContext`, for example :

```
void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DeviceInfo selectedDeviceInfo = (DeviceInfo)((Button)sender).DataContext;
}
```